# Como se modifica el método si cambio los años de int a date

Tags: java

Os cuento el problema.
Tengo un array de cartas de rol, cada carta tiene una serie de atributos entre ellos año de creación que lo he creado como INT.  Este es mi método.

```
public CartaDeRol devCartaAntigua() {
    int antigua = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int posicionCartaMasAntigua = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (mazo[i].getAnioCreacion() < antigua) {
            antigua = mazo[i].getAnioCreacion();
        }
        posicionCartaMasAntigua = i;
    }
    return mazo[posicionCartaMasAntigua];
}
```

Ahora mis preguntas son:
 1. ¿Cómo hago para poner los años de creación como `date`?
 2. ¿Cómo hago para que el `date` solo aparezcan los años?
 3. ¿Cómo se modifica el método en consecuencia?

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No uses java.util.Date, es una clase antigua y obsoleta. Mira el paquete java.time

Comment: bueno yo solo he usado date peor time me vale pero esa no es la parte imporante de la pregunta jaja como hago para que solo salga los año y como modifico el metodo

Comment: ¿Porqué deseas usar `date` para almacenar solo el año? Eso no tiene un sentido práctico.

Comment: Pues no deseo usar date para el año. Es que me piden el año solo y en principio use un String luego a ver que tenia que operar pues use un INT y ahora pensé que un DATE seria mas correcto pero me da igual dejarlo en INT. 
También sea cierto mi profesor es muy puntilloso y tiquismiquis.

Comment: Entiendo, ya eso entonces va a depender de tu profesor, los argumentos que tu le presentes y los que él te exponga. Si lo que vas a almacenar es una fecha debes usar `date`, si es solo el valor del año, puedes usar `int` o `string`. Como debes realizar comparaciones, lo más adecuado es `int`. Me parece que con eso tienes. Saludos

Comment: Échale un ojo a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678774/date-in-java-with-just-year)